# Wolfram Mathematica: why is the plot not visible?

Tags: graphing-functions, 3d, math-software, mathematica, wolfram-alpha

simple question regarding Wolfram Mathematica:

Why is the plot not showing?
(See screenshot)

[image]

(I am new to Wolfram Mathematica)

Thankful for any input.

Comment: Isn't there a mathematica stack?

Comment: Works when I tried it, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot3d+%5Bx%5E3-6xy%2By%5E3%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C4%7D%2C%7By%2C0%2C4%7D%5D)

Comment: Because you wrote $xy$ when you should have written $x\ y$ or $x*y$.

Comment: Following up on José Carlos Santos' comment: the colors of the variables is a clue. Notice that the $x$ and $y$ are a different color from the $xy$.  The $x$ and $y$ are set by the iteration structures, whereas $xy$ is an unknown.

Comment: When I wrote plot3d [x^3-6xy+y^3,{x,0,4},{y,0,4}] it worked fine.